# Printing issue running a "Designed for iPad" App on macOS

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui

The code bellow works on iPad but not on macOS using "designed for iPad" mode. I get this error.

```
CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

How can I modify the code to runs correctly on macOS?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("print"){
                prt()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func prt(){
        let htmlString = "<h1>Hello World</h1>"
        let formatter: UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: htmlString)
        let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)
        printInfo.jobName = "test"
        printInfo.outputType = .general
        let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
        printController.printInfo = printInfo
        printController.showsNumberOfCopies = true
        printController.printFormatter = formatter
        let controller = UIViewController()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: { _, _, _ in
                printController.printFormatter = nil
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds similar to the problem reported here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/740510?page=1#773438022. Any idea if this is a Sonoma regression? I don't have an earlier macOS version on which to test.

Comment: I run it on Somona too

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a solution, but I also encountered this problem yesterday (what are the odds?).  I just filed the following feedback report and would encourage others encountering this issues to also file a report:

> FB13420491: Print command hangs when running a "Designed for iPad" App
> on macOS: CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0

My app is written in Obj-C and the code is similar to what you have above *(at least in my case, I don't think the dispatch_async is necessary, since the action is already invoked on the main queue)*:

```
- (IBAction)print:(id)sender {
    UISimpleTextPrintFormatter * printFormatter = [[UISimpleTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithText:@"TEXT"];
    if ( printFormatter ) {
        UIPrintInfo * printInfo = UIPrintInfo.printInfo;
        printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGrayscale;

        printFormatter.color = nil; // FB13418343 default is labelColor (i.e. white in Dark Mode)

        UIPrintInteractionController * printController = UIPrintInteractionController.sharedPrintController;
        printController.printInfo = printInfo;
        printController.printFormatter = printFormatter;
        [printController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:^(UIPrintInteractionController * _Nonnull printInteractionController, BOOL completed, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            NSLog(@"print completed: %u %@", completed, error);
        }];
    }
}
```

The completion is never invoked (unless I hit Command-P twice):

With CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE=YES I get this:

```
CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace:
  <RemotePDEServiceInterface+13092>
   <RemotePDEServiceInterface+11960>
    <RemotePDEServiceInterface+10308>
     <main+9188>
      <-[_NSCollectionViewCore _computePrefetchCandidatesForVisibleBounds:futureVisibleBounds:prefetchVector:notifyDelegateIfNe
       <-[_NSCollectionViewCore _computePrefetchCandidatesForRect:]+232>
        <-[_NSCollectionViewCore _layoutItems]+172>
         <-[NSCollectionView layout]+304>
          <___NSViewLayout_block_invoke+592>
           <NSPerformVisuallyAtomicChange+108>
            <_NSViewLayout+96>
             <__36-[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:]_block_invoke+364>
              <NSPerformVisuallyAtomicChange+108>
               <-[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:]+100>
                <__36-[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:]_block_invoke+688>
                 <NSPerformVisuallyAtomicChange+108>
                  <-[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:]+100>
                   <__36-[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:]_block_invoke+688>
                    <NSPerformVisuallyAtomicChange+108>
                     <-[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:]+100>
                      <__36-[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:]_block_invoke+688>
                       <NSPerformVisuallyAtomicChange+108>
                        <-[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:]+100>
                         <__36-[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:]_block_invoke+688>
                          <NSPerformVisuallyAtomicChange+108>
                           <-[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:]+100>
                            <__36-[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:]_block_invoke+688>
                             <NSPerformVisuallyAtomicChange+108>
                              <-[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:]+100>
                               <__36-[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:]_block_invoke+688>
                                <NSPerformVisuallyAtomicChange+108>
                                 <-[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:]+100>
                                  <__56-[NSView _layoutSubtreeIfNeededAndAllowTemporaryEngine:]_block_invoke+796>
                                   <NSPerformVisuallyAtomicChange+108>
                                    <-[NSView _layoutSubtreeIfNeededAndAllowTemporaryEngine:]+100>
                                     <NSPerformVisuallyAtomicChange+108>
                                      <-[NSView layoutSubtreeIfNeeded]+96>
                                       <-[NSWindow(NSConstraintBasedLayoutInternal) _layoutViewTree]+104>
                                        <-[NSWindow(NSConstraintBasedLayoutInternal) layoutIfNeeded]+240>
                                         <__NSWindowGetDisplayCycleObserverForLayout_block_invoke+364>
                                          <NSDisplayCycleObserverInvoke+168>
                                           <NSDisplayCycleFlush+644>
                                            <__37+[NSDisplayCycle currentDisplayCycle]_block_invoke.7+28>
                                             <___NSMainRunLoopPerformBlockInModes_block_invoke+44>
                                              <__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__+28>
                                               <__CFRunLoopDoBlocks+356>
                                               <__CFRunLoopRun+812>
                                               <CFRunLoopRunSpecific+608>
                                               <-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]+212>
                                               <-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:]+100>
                                               <-[UINSPDFPrintingView _generatePDF]+324>
                                               <-[UINSPDFPrintingView pdfDocument]+72>
                                               <-[UINSPDFPrintingView knowsPageRange:]+72>
                                               <-[NSView(NSPrinting2) _knowsPagesFirst:last:]+176>
                                               <__59-[NSConcretePrintOperation(NSInternal) _validatePagination]_block_invoke+21
                                               <NSPerformVisuallyAtomicChange+108>
                                               <-[NSConcretePrintOperation(NSInternal) _validatePagination]+124>
                                               <-[NSConcretePrintOperation(NSInternal) _firstPageNumber]+24>
                                               <-[NSConcretePrintOperation pageRange]+24>
                                               <__67-[NSPrintPanel _makePrintWindowControllerWithPrintOperation:sheet:]_block_i
                                               <PMAppendToSummaryString+96940>
                                               <__CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__+148>
                                               <___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke+88>
                                               <_CFXRegistrationPost+440>
                                               <_CFXNotificationPost+764>
                                               <-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]+88>
                                               <PMPrintPanelSetAppThumbnailViewPrivate+3460>
                                               <-[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKeys:count:maybeOldValues
                                               <-[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:]+
                                               <_NSSetObjectValueAndNotify+284>
                                               <main+56728>
                                               <__NSDICTIONARY_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__+24>
                                               <-[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]+288>
                                               <main+53188>
                                               <main+161412>
                                               <main+148520>
                                               <PMPrintPanelSetAppThumbnailViewPrivate+32920>
                                               <PMAppendToSummaryString+93600>
                                               <-[NSWindowController _windowDidLoad]+620>
                                               <-[NSWindowController window]+84>
                                               <-[NSPrintPanel beginSheetUsingPrintInfo:onWindow:completionHandler:]+440>
                                               <__91-[NSConcretePrintOperation runOperationModalForWindow:delegate:didRunSelect
                                               <-[NSConcretePrintOperation runOperationModalForWindow:delegate:didRunSelector:c
                                               <__65-[UINSPrintingController _runModalPrintOperation:withCompletion:]_block_inv
                                               <__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__+28>
                                               <__CFRunLoopDoBlocks+356>
                                               <__CFRunLoopRun+812>
                                               <CFRunLoopRunSpecific+608>
                                               <RunCurrentEventLoopInMode+292>
                                               <ReceiveNextEventCommon+220>
                                               <_BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter+76>
                                               <_DPSNextEvent+660>
                                               <-[NSApplication(NSEventRouting) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:de
                                               <-[NSApplication run]+476>
                                               <NSApplicationMain+880>
                                               <+[NSWindow _savedFrameFromString:]+0>
                                               <UINSApplicationMain+972>
                                               <UIApplicationMain+148>
                                               <main+204>                                               <start+2360>
```

Comment: One (not ideal) workaround I found is to pre-render the content to PDF, then print that using `.printItem` instead. However, this same backtrace still occurs when printing pre-rendered PDF data, and I'm still seeing a similar problem in another case where I just pass data from a PDFView as `pdfView.document.dataRepresentation`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a temporary solution solution for my issue using WKWebView.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showPicker = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("print"){
                  prt()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func prt(){
        let htmlString = "<h1>Hello World</h1>"
        if (isiOSAppOnMac()){
           _ = WebPrintPageRendererAndPrint(htmlString: htmlString)
        }else{
           printiOS(htmlString: htmlString)
        }
    }
    
    func printiOS(htmlString:  String){
            let htmlString = htmlString
            let formatter: UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: htmlString)
            let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)
            printInfo.jobName = "test"
            printInfo.outputType = .general
            let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
            printController.printInfo = printInfo
            printController.showsNumberOfCopies = true
            printController.printFormatter = formatter
                printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: { _, _, _ in
                    printController.printFormatter = nil
                })
            }
    }
    
func isiOSAppOnMac() -> Bool {
  if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
    return ProcessInfo.processInfo.isiOSAppOnMac
  }
  return false
}
```

WebPrintPageRenderer.swift file

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebPrintPageRendererAndPrint: UIPrintPageRenderer,WKNavigationDelegate {
    let htmlString: String
    let wb = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))


    init(htmlString: String) {
        self.htmlString = htmlString
        super.init()
        wb.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            let printFormatter = self.wb.viewPrintFormatter()
            self.addPrintFormatter(printFormatter, startingAtPageAt: 0)
            let info = UIPrintInfo.printInfo()
            info.outputType = .general
            info.orientation = .portrait
            info.jobName = "test"
            
            let printInteractionController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared

            printInteractionController.printPageRenderer = self
            printInteractionController.printInfo = info
            printInteractionController.present(animated: true)
         
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Good idea to use WKWebView.  I had tried something similar with UITextView but it did not help.

Comment: I was similarly able to work around the problem of printing simple text by using WKWebView, but unfortunately this workaround did not work in the other problem scenario that I've encountered, which is when attempting to print NSData from a nontrivial PDF file. Printing using WKWebView also failed when I loaded the WKWebView from a URLRequest pointing to the problematic PDF file. I observed that this scenario is PDF-file-specific; everything seems fine with trivial PDFs created from a TextEdit print preview, but it fails with real-world PDF documents (again only under macOS; iOS is fine).

Comment: For what it’s worth, I found that the problem printing PDF data seems to be dependent on the number of pages. When I added a 3rd page to my trivial test PDF it similarly failed; 1-2 pages seems to work.